# The issue of checking if pointer is NULL or "zero size" in Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel

In Linux kernel sources there is some indicator called [`ZERO_SIZE_PTR`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.10/source/include/linux/slab.h#L131) to indicate zero sized kmalloc requests. But also there is a macro [`ZERO_OR_NULL_PTR()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.10/source/include/linux/slab.h#L133) which checks some pointer if it's "zero size" or "NULL". The code:

```
/*
 * ZERO_SIZE_PTR will be returned for zero sized kmalloc requests.
 *
 * Dereferencing ZERO_SIZE_PTR will lead to a distinct access fault.
 *
 * ZERO_SIZE_PTR can be passed to kfree though in the same way that NULL can.
 * Both make kfree a no-op.
 */
#define ZERO_SIZE_PTR ((void *)16)

#define ZERO_OR_NULL_PTR(x) ((unsigned long)(x) <= \
                (unsigned long)ZERO_SIZE_PTR)
```

The check looks like `ptr <= (void *)16`.
In simple terms, it means that NULL-pointer is the pointer from `0` to `15`, and zero size pointer is `16`.
So pointers from `17` and higher are supposed to be valid. Is that proper that `15` is invalid (NULL) but `17` is valid? It seems to me that valid pointers do not start from 17, but from higher numbers.

I mean perhaps it will be more logical to check such way `x == NULL || x == ZERO_SIZE_PTR` (without involving `1`-`15` range).

Comment: This does not check if the pointer is valid, so where valid pointers start is irrelevant.

Comment: It might be more logical to do what you suggest, but `ptr <= 16` is _faster_. The kernel is famous for doing _insane_ things for speed as long as they're encapsulated in a macro with a clean interface. And, there's no valid pointer within the range 1-15 because to make this work well, the first page (at 0x00000000) needs to be R/W protected in the MMU, so no harm/no foul. And, it allows other values in the 1-15 range to serve as future error codes, just as 16 does in the macro. So, the range approach is arguably better.

Comment: @CraigEstey You should post it as an answer! But what about `17` and higher? Is `16` the border value? Or the range can be extended?

Comment: `ZERO_SIZE_PTR` as stated in the comment was chosen only by purpose to have distinct (Craig seems are not familiar with kernel error codes) crashes (they will have value of 16 in the %r0: %rax on x86_64, for example). Basically it's the same as NULL and otherwise we may simple return NULL and do not have such macro at all.